# What is the best publisher for a computer science book

Tags: book, publisher, science

I'm a newbie...

I've some material I want to submit to an editor
for evaluation feedback about content relevance and quality
and the possibility of publishing a book...

```
What is the best way to face this challenge...
What options do I have...
(...)
What challenges will I face..
What mountain should i climb...
What god shall I praise...
How many monsters should I slay...
(Ooopppsss... getting to literary... CUT!!!)
(CMD:RESET-BRAIN DATA:BOOK-INFO)
```

Any advice are welcome...
Any experience share are welcome too...

[Field]
This will be a book about computing,
Focus on how to get more productive using interfaces...
Uncovering so often re-pushed practices hidding better approaches.
Delineating strategies to approach OS interfaces...

```
[Audience]
1.  Computer novices (usually desktop users)
    who feel overwellmed by quantity

2.  Novices evolving to medium
    Usually passing from GUI to CLI (+power)

3.  System administrators
    What to better/quicker access their tasks

4.  Programmers
    Quick access filesystem, documentation, etc.

*   and many other,
    The condition is: be a computing device user...
_
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First, Some Points to Consider**

Editors are very busy, of course, so you only have a sentence or two to get their attention.

**Attention Getting Concept**

In order to get the attention of an editor you need to be sure you are writing on a concept that is current, valuable and a large number of people are interested in, but is focused enough that it is a book and not the Internet rewritten.

**Readers Buy Structure**

Make sure your book is structured well and "tells the story of the technology" you are writing about.

Imagine a person looking for information on spider monkeys.  She goes to Google and does a search: Okay I just did that

[https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=spider+monkey](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=spider%20monkey)

Google says

> About 5,590,000 results

As a reader I cannot read all of that in my lifetime.  Plus a lot of it probably isn't relative and much of it is probably repeated.
As a reader, what I want is a structured volume of information that is related to what I'm interested in.

**How can you, the writer, know what the reader wants?**

You must be interested in the technology you are writing about.  You must want to read the book that you are writing and the reason you are writing it is that the book doesn't really exist yet.

> “If there's a book that you want to read, but it hasn't been written
> yet, then you must write it.”  ~Toni Morrison

**More On Structure**

The acquistions editor will surely ask for an outline of your non-fiction book so make sure you create an outline which displays that you are (again) "telling the story of the technology" that you are writing about.

**Let Your Own Reading Guide You**

You are a reader and you know that if you wanted to read a book about spider monkeys you would want it to progress logically through the items of interest that would allow you to read as little as possible but learn as much as possible about the subject.

**No Starch Press**
No Starch seems to be a decent publishing company who is growing and publishing quite a few books.
They have some nice guidelines that you can use to target them specifically but will also be instructive as to what you need to do for any technology publisher.
https://www.nostarch.com/writeforus.htm

Good luck on your project.

Comment: Thanks... good info... hope more info/opinions will come...